# to pass $_POST values from form action in url using?

Tags: php, html

my code is as follows

```
<form method="post" action="raf_details.php?raf=<? echo $_POST['raf']; ?>">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">
  <tr style="background-color:#C1C1C1" align="center">
    <td>RAF</td>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td>Search</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E8F8FF" style="background-color:#E1E1E1">
    <td><input type="text" name="raf" id="raf" value="<?php echo $_POST['raf'];?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?=$_POST['phone'];?>"/></td>
    <td><input type="image" src="../images/btnFind.png" id="find" name="find"  /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

But it is not fecthing $_POST['raf'] value in url 
my url is just showing

```
http://localhost:8888/ample/payment/raf_details.php?raf=
```

Comment: YOu can directly use `$_POST['raf']` in raf_details.php without passing in action URL.

Comment: Do you get anything in <input type="text" name="raf" id="raf" value="<?php echo $_POST['raf'];?>"

Comment: check that `$_POST['raf']` has value or not?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `get` method for your form like

```
<form method="get" action="raf_details.php">
```

Then on submitting your form the url will be like

```
/raf_details.php?raf=somthing
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's true. However you can access it from $_GET['raf']. You can send get and post params simultaneously.
But a good practice solution would be this:

```
<!-- remove the raf from the action -->
<form method="post" action="raf_details.php">
<!-- ****************add this line ****************** -->
    <input type="hidden" name="raf" value="<? echo $_POST['raf']; ?>" />
<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">
  <tr style="background-color:#C1C1C1" align="center">
    <td>RAF</td>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td>Search</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E8F8FF" style="background-color:#E1E1E1">
    <td><input type="text" name="raf" id="raf" value="<?php echo $_POST['raf'];?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?=$_POST['phone'];?>"/></td>
    <td><input type="image" src="../images/btnFind.png" id="find" name="find"  /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

we can send paramaters using GET and POST. if you want pass variables in url use the GET method.

```
<form method="get" action="raf_details.php">
```